# For python, why isn't my "setter" and "getter" in my class being called?

Tags: python, class, methods, getter, setter

The goal of this program is to use classes to create create a Car object. It firsts asks the users for the year and make of the car and will then ask for the number of times the car will accelerate and brake and it adds 5 or subtracts 5 depending on the amount the user inputs. I don't know the proper terms but the methods in the class were referred to as "setters" and "getters", where we set what we want to be called and then retrieve it with another method. My problem is when I created a function for asking for the year input, it worked fine, but when I tried to move it to the class it no longer is asked for, as in the program automatically skips to the next question and the year question isn't shown. My second problem is the accelerate and brake equations aren't working. It comes up with the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'int'". This is my current program:

```
class Car:
    
    #constructor of the class
    def __init__(self):
        self.year = None
        self.make = None
        self.speed = 0
        

    def setYear(self, value, prompt):
        self.year = value
        while(True):
            try:
                value = int(input(prompt))

                valueStringConvert = len(str(value))

                if (valueStringConvert == 4):
                    return value

                else:
                    print('Error Msg: Year must be 4 digits.\n')
        
        
            except ValueError: # catch the data entry issue
                print('Error Msg: Non Numbers entered.\n')

    def setMake(self, value):
        self.make = value

    def setSpeed(self):
        self.speed = 0

    def getYear(self):
        return self.year

    def getMake(self):
        return self.make
    
    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.speed

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed = self.speed = self.speed + 5

    def brake(self):
        self.brake = self.brake - 5
   
def main():

    myCar = Car()
    #year = getYearEntry('\nPlease enter the year model of the car: \n')
    year = myCar.getYear()

    make = getStringEntry('\nPlease enter the make of the car: \n')
    speed = 0

    

    accelerateAmount = getIntegerEntry('\nHow many times did you accelerate?\n')
    accelerateResult = myCar.accelerate()

    brakeAmount = getIntegerEntry('\nHow many times did you brake?\n')
    brakeResult = myCar.brake()

    displayResult(year, make, brakeResult, accelerateResult, myCar)

def displayResult(year, make, brakeResult, accelerateResult, myCar):
 
    print('')
    print('-' * 30)
    print('Car Make: ', myCar.getYear())
    print('-' * 30)

#def getYearEntry(prompt):
#     while(True):
#         try:
#             value = int(input(prompt))

#             valueStringConvert = len(str(value))

#             if (valueStringConvert == 4):
#                 return value

#             else:
#                 print('Error Msg: Year must be 4 digits.\n')
        
        
#         except ValueError: # catch the data entry issue
#             print('Error Msg: Non Numbers entered.\n')

#This will get users entry of an integer data
def getIntegerEntry(prompt): 
    while(True):
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))

            if(value > 0):
                return value

            else:
                print('Error Msg: Numbers less than 0 is not allowed.')
        
     
        except ValueError: # catch the data entry issue
            print('Error Msg: Non Numbers entered.')
```

The commented year parts are what originally worked but I don't think we are allowed to use functions since this project is about utilizing classes. Also the display results isn't finished yet because I'm stuck on the first parts. I'm really sorry if I am not making sense as I am very new to this so please ask if you need clarification on anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok since the question is asked with a genuine spirit/desire to learn and explore, here are a few pointers:

- Issue 1 - `setYear()` doesn't get called anywhere (you're calling `getYear()`). Also, not sure why you're passing `value` into it, and the assignment of `self.year` should probably happen last, once you've checked for all the error conditions
- Issue 2 - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'int'
  It's all down to the fact that your method `brake()` and the (desired but not actually existent) instance variable `brake` have the same name, so pick a different name for one of them and also initialise the variable (to zero?) in `__init__`

  ```
    def brake(self):
        self.brake = self.brake - 5
  ```

Comment: For issue 1, do I just put the code in setYear into getYear and just scratch setYear alltogether then ? And what does assignment of self.year mean ? Is that what I did in __init__ ? Thank you for helping me

Comment: From a software design pattern point of view, it probably makes more sense to have setYear similar to the other setter methods, and have the input parsing external to that. That way the Car class can be reused in other contexts, where it could be other code setting the values, not just user input.
`self.anything` are instance variables belonging to a specific car instances (a car object is an instance of the Car class). Also I just realized that you probably intended to use `self.speed` instead of `self.brake` in the `brake()` method.

Comment: Also, a better pattern for printing out the car would be to override `__repr__(self):` and return a string that summarises the car's properties in a format you desire. Then let python do the magic, while you simply do: `print(myCar)`